# async not calling back?

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm using async waterfall

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall

Is it okay to not call back on failure states? Will repeatedly doing that cause memory leaks?

Instead of calling back with an error just don't call back at all and not run the final callback.

Answer (score 0):

Async waterfall model is a framework which allows us to easily track down the exception handling by using its error handling mechanism. So its always better to handle the extreme edge cases - error & result. And about memory leak - since the whole operation is performed in an asynchronous environment and being controlled event-loop so if the memory leak happens it might not be due to the error (which is being traced back) to its respective callback.

To answer whether we can do it or not ? - Yes we can do it.

example -

```
async.waterfall ([
    getInfo,
    updateInfo

], function ( error, result){
          if ( result ){ console.log("Look I am done success:"+result);}
});

function getInfo (callback ){ callback ( null,"Hello"); }

function updateInfo ( data, callback ){ callback (null, data + " world" ); }
```

But if we tweak the function updateInfo() with a validation for exception handling, then the existing waterfall will fail share any outcome. ( In the following example the error won't float up to the async.waterfall as its not being taken care of )

```
function updateInfo ( data, callback ){
if ( typeof data === 'string') {    
    callback (null, data + " world" );
} else {
    callback ("Expects a String as input", null);
}
}
```